# Set cookie on connections from same ip?

Tags: http, cookies, browser, setcookie

A browser creates 3 connections to my server for document request. If two other computers sends a document request from the same router (same time) I'll have 9 connections from the same ip.

Should I Set cookies with different values for all of the connections then wait and see which one the browser selected?

Comment: Can you clarify what's your problem? You shouldn't even care whether they're from the same IP or even browser (a single browser can create a normal session and incognito session, and your app should handle them separately)

Comment: From a user I get the initial request(.html) on one connection, the other subrequests (.css, .js) on different connections. I need to set a unique cookie for this user, but I cant use "Set-Cookie" with the same value in a response to all of theses requests, because I dont know if the other two subrequests belongs to the same user. Should include the header only for the initial document requests?

Comment: Er, why would the .css and .js need cookies? Static content don't need them unless you somehow serve different style and script depending on the user.

Comment: Okey then problem solved. What if the user disables cookies completely, will all modern browsers stop sending the cookieheader(with name and value) as well?

Comment: There will be useragent at least, so headers will still be there

Comment: Yes of course headers will be there, but will the **cookie**-header be there so I still can identify the user by the value of the cookie. The useragent can be same for multiple clients

Comment: Yes, every consecutive request after it receives the cookie will include it as long as it's not expired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215446/discussion-between-martheen-and-arre).